# Hide subplot in Plotly with dropdown

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I am trying to create a interactive graph in Plotly (in r) where a user can select a grouping variable. I've managed to do this with a stacked bargraph, but I have not been successful in creating a dodged bargraph.
Below is an example of what I would like to create (but done in ggplot). When a user sees the plot, only the blue bar is shown and all other labels on x-axis are hidden. When the user selects a grouping variable, the blue bar is hidden but the grey bars are shown (and the "all" label on x-axis is hidden).
(*The graph I am actually trying to create is obviously more complex, but for demonstration here is a simple graph)*

[image: Example graph]

**The plotly part**
Now, it's my understanding that to create a facet (like the one in ggplot), I need to use plotly::subplot(). I have almost managed to create what I want in plotly, but the axis for the hidden bars are still visible. I can only hide the bars, there is a lot of empty space.
[image: Example plot in plotly]

**My question**
Can I show/hide a subplot? If not, is there a workaround, e.g. hide axis for a subplot.

**Example code**

```
# Packages ----
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)


# Data ----
data1 <- cbind(
  "all", 
  iris %>% summarise(
    m = mean(Sepal.Width)
  )) %>% as_tibble()
names(data1)[1] <- "Species"
data2 <- group_by(iris, Species) %>% 
  summarise(
    m = mean(Sepal.Width))
data <- rbind(data1, data2)


# Plot ----
# Plot grand mean
graph1 <- filter(data, Species == "all") %>%
  plot_ly() %>%
  add_bars(name = label_x,
           x = ~Species, y = ~m,
           visible = TRUE)
# Plot mean for groups
graph2 <- filter(data, Species != "all") %>% 
  plot_ly() %>%
  add_bars(name = label_x,
           x = ~Species, y = ~m,
           visible = FALSE) # groups hidden by default
# Combine plots
graph <- plotly::subplot(graph1, graph2, shareY = TRUE)


# Create a filter -----
my_filter <- list(
  #1st filter - Only show 'All'
  list(
    label = "all",
    args = list(
      list(visible = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE))
    )
  ),
  #2nd filter - Only show 'groups'
  list(
    label = "groups",
    args = list(
      list(visible = c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE))
    )
  )
)


# Edit plot ----
graph %>% 
  layout(
    updatemenus = list(
      list(y = 0.9,
           buttons = my_filter)
    ))
```